# Help me identify this font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

This font is from the movie Swordfish where the hacker (Hugh Jackman) is working on the laptop / computer screen. Please note the letters C E F G Q. Can you please help identify this?

[image: laptop screenshot from swordfish movie]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. We have some requirements for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to meet those guidelines - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I pinged a typography blogger Deve Addey on Twitter and they said "Oh! That’s Bank Gothic - the *other* most sci-fi of fonts, after Eurostile Bold Extended."